# ensuring uniform #defines among all object files

Tags: c++, configuration, linker, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

How can I ensure that all object files in my C++ project were compiled with the same conditional defines?  I.e. if they were not, I want to ensure a linker error pointing to the conflicting define.  I want this to happen even with aggressive dead-code elimination by the compiler.  Is there a known technique for this?

Comment: `#include <CommonDefines.hpp>`...

Comment: (I. e., organize your project and be disciplined.)

Comment: don't add `#define WIN32` into the middle of your cpp file and you'll probably be fine;   but on a more serious note, this is what your cmake/make file should be doing

Answer (score 0):

You can't; individual invocations of the compiler are just that - independent.  The only way you can ensure this result is to have a single common source of all of the definitions, whether that's a command line specified in your makefile or a common header file, for example.

Comment: Compilations are independent, but when it's all linked, isn't there a way to cause a linker error if incompatible compile-time flags were used?   E.g. a function or variable with a given name gets defined differently based on the flags; but that runs afoul of the one-definition-rule...

Comment: If link-time error isn't possible, what would be the least error-prone way to do a runtime check of this on startup?